# Can't get my js script to work inside wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I enqueued a file "my-script" inside wordpress through function.php in order to add some jQuery functionality to the site. The main purpose was to hide the carousel controls if only one item was present (one image or div) Unfortunately I can't even get wordpress to even read the file. I placed a simple alert to show after document is loaded and nothing happens. This is how I enqueued several scripts including "my-script"

```
/* Enqueuing Scripts */
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.12.4', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true); // all the bootstrap JavaScript goodness
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js' , array('jquery'), true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts');

function enqueue_my_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-ot-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dynamic.css');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_styles');
```

and this is the contents of 'my-script' file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert( "Test My-Script" );
});
```

Nothing happens. I currently have the divs with the carousel controls hidden through CSS, but would like to get it working so the site evaluates if it has just one item before hiding them

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where is the 'my-script.js'  ? I mean in the folders tree. Are your "style.css" and "dynamic.css" correctly loaded ?

Comment: Hi Adrien. everything else loaded fine. 'my-script.js' is in a JS folder in the same location where the theme css is

Comment: http://jobdashboard.net/vivaink/faq/

Comment: Try this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ...`, putting `jQuery` in front instead of `$`, and adding `$` as parameter to the callback function.

Comment: The alert displayed perfectly! I just added the code inside my-script.js to hide the controls if there is only one child inside '.carousel-inner' but nothing changes. Any thoughts?

Comment: @trincot is right, you need to use jQuery in stead of $. But just in case, it still doesn't work, try to add the script's version (or just false) to your wp_enqueue_script function.

Comment: You can also use WP's jQuery, but not specifying a path at all, just `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')`. If you have trouble with some of your code, that should be the subject of another question.

Comment: 'jQuery(document).ready(function($){               // on document ready

  if($('.carousel-inner .item').is(':only-child')) {
   $('.carousel-indicators, .carousel-control').hide();
  }

});'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress you cannot use `$` just like that to reference your own loaded jQuery. This is because WordPress has called `jQuery.noConflict()`.

One solution is to reference `jQuery` instead of `$`. If you still want your script to use `$`, then write this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // ... your code that can reference $ comes here.
});
```

Don't forget to specify the `$` as callback function parameter.

Comment: Hi trincot, I was able to get the script to show the alert. but now I can't get it to hide the navigation controls of bootstrap carousel through jquery hide()

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question about that. Follow-up questions are not suitable for comments, and this question is quite different, so please create a new question. I will be happy to look at it (as many others, I am sure).

Comment: Great! Thank you Trincot!

Comment: Sorry about that! I will review previous questions... new at this! Thanks again!